# AWS SQS and SES dependency libraries effect each other

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dependencies, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I'm trying to use imports from SES and SQS at the same time but the combination causes an error to be thrown with the .withBody method. I'm guessing it's to do with the dependencies but they are at the latest version.

Error:(116,54) java:incompatible types:com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Body cannot be converted to java.lang.String

```
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiveMessageRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.*;

public void email(S3Event event, Person person, Boolean error) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String emailText = null;
    if (error) {
        emailText = "Error! No image in file!";
    } else {
        try {
            emailText = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String key = event.getRecords().get(0).getS3().getObject().getKey();
    AmazonSimpleEmailService client =            
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
    Body body = new Body().withText(new Content().withData(emailText));
    SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withDestination(
        new Destination().withToAddresses(person.getEmail()))
            .withMessage(new Message()
                .withBody(new Body().withHtml(new 
Content().withCharset("UTF8").withData(emailText)))
                    .withSubject(new Content()
                        .withCharset("UTF-8").withData("Message from passport service.")))
            .withSource(person.getEmail());
    client.sendEmail(request);
}

public void getBaseCodeFromSQS() {
AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient();

try {
    ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest("https://sqs.eu-  
west-1.amazonaws.com/416031944655/TISFEXP-PSS-2-QUEUE");
        List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
        for (Message message : messages) {
            LOGGER.info("MessageId:     " + message.getMessageId());
            LOGGER.info("ReceiptHandle: " + message.getReceiptHandle());
            LOGGER.info("MD5OfBody:     " + message.getMD5OfBody());
            LOGGER.info("Body:          " + message.getBody());
            for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : message.getAttributes().entrySet())     
            {
                LOGGER.info("Attribute - Name:  " + entry.getKey());
                LOGGER.info("Attribute - Value: " + entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e);
    }
}

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.634</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.634</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.634</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Message class defined in both SES and SQS packages. You are using the Message class defined in the SQS package. You should use the one defined in SES package instead.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/Message.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/model/Message.html

```
SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest().withDestination(
        new Destination().withToAddresses(person.getEmail()))
            .withMessage(new com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.Message()
                .withBody(new Body().withHtml(new 
Content().withCharset("UTF8").withData(emailText)))
                    .withSubject(new Content()
                        .withCharset("UTF-8").withData("Message from passport service.")))
            .withSource(person.getEmail());
```

Comment: Much appreciated @Abhiram. I'd just ground it down to working out the SQS  message type was being used in the SES but didn't quite know how to do the code!